# Django URL didn't match any of URL config

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, django-urls

The errors message is:

```
Using the URLconf defined in Blog.urls,
Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/doc/
^admin/
^post/ ^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$

The current URL, post/1458/, didn't match any of these.
```

Why? I think `post/1485/` match `^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$`

My root url config is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^post/', include('posts.urls')),
)
```

Then, my `posts/urls.py` is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', 'post.views.post_page'),
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current setup would match URLs like this:

```
/post/post/1485/
```

Make `posts/urls.py` look like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', 'post.views.post_page'),
)
```

Comment: Classic. I've seen any number of Django newbies make this error.